# Submitting Ajax request from external javascript file in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to submit an ajax request from an external JavaScript file in ASP.NET MVC. I'm getting a 500. What am I doing wrong?

Ajax call (From external JS file)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Home/AjaxEndpoint',
    data: { jsonData: "testing" },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: successFunc,
    error: errorFunc
});
```

Controller Action Method (That should be catching the request)

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public void AjaxEndpoint()
    {
        var thing = 1 + 2;
    }

    // AJAX endpoint for GetProducts.js
    [HttpPost]
    public void AjaxEndpoint(string jsonData)
    {
        var thing = 1 + 2;
    }

}
```

Error I'm getting
[image]

Comment: You need to put your code in the question, not images of it. And remove the `contentType` option (your not stringifying the data)

Comment: Please do not edit the question with the answer (I have removed it). Add your own answer and accept it to close this out.

Comment: If you have a proposed solution, such as "remove the contentType option", please create an answer so that I can accept it rather than burying it in the comments of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to remove the `contentType` option

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Home/AjaxEndpoint',
    data: { jsonData: "testing" },
    dataType: "json",
    success: successFunc,
    error: errorFunc
});
```

or alternatively, stringify the data

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Home/AjaxEndpoint',
    data: JSON.stringify({ jsonData: "testing" }),// modify
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: successFunc,
    error: errorFunc
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call needs to be to an ActionResult in the controller,  The controller performs and returns the data to the page

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ajaxcall(string ids)
    {
        String Data = code to perform
        return Json(Data);
    }
```

this is the basic idea.  Javascript makes the call and uses the json data returned on the clients page